# How do I place specific characters in a specific place within a file?

Tags: python

I want to be able to add a specific character into my file, using python code.

I have attempted using read functions, meaning lists, but those come up with an error of "`TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method`"

I believe this means that python can not write a character into a specific place using the list function

Incorrect way:

file:  `1)5`

Code:

```py
while true:
  with open ('file','w') as f:
    f.writeline[0]=+1
  with open ('file','r') as f:
    fc = f.read()
    print (fc)
```

Expected output:
`5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15....`

I assumed that this line of code would increase the five until I stopped the program, but instead it sent the error code described earlier. Is there a way to write the code so that it does it as expected?

Comment: Your syntax is not correct, how could it run? Please fix your post.

Comment: Is it always the case that the new text is the same length (in *bytes*) as the old?

Comment: @DavisHerring , Well, it depends. Unless I am adding more information to the file, it should stay the same, should it not? All I am doing is replacing the info in the file with another integer..

Comment: @knh190 , fixed. I forgot to capitalize the 'True'

Comment: Please describe with more detail of your file data, your code and what are you expected for??

Comment: @LêTưThành , The file data is just meant to represent an integer that is to be changed using the code listed. The program execution should continue looping and adding a single integer value to the '5' in the file. My code is in hope that the program sees the 'writeline', and notices the '[]'. It will read the value within the brackets, and see that I want to change the index of 0, to a value of one greater than that (After seeing the '=+1'). Does that help clarify?

Comment: @TheFlooBearer, just give us an `example input` and `example output` (after done the loop)

Comment: @LêTưThành , okay, I think I see what you mean. Recheck it, sorry if I am not being clear. I am not entirely sure how to put it into words I guess..

Comment: @TheFlooBearer do you want to write a list of integers or characters in the file?

Comment: @Amiy , I would just like to change the singular value within the file, multiple times before closing the program

Comment: @TheFlooBearer if you want to store data in your file and change it, then why not use formats used for data storage like JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you would need to build a function to update a single character. I think this would work, but I literally wrote it in like three minutes, so take caution...

```py
def write_at_index(filename,y_pos,x_pos,character):
    """Write a character 'character' at the given index"""
    lines = 0 //begin lines outside scope of the with statement.
    with open(filename,"r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        if len(lines)<y_pos:
            raise Exception('y pos out of bounds')
        if len(lines[y_pos]) < x_pos
            raise Exception('x_pos out of bounds')
        lines[y_pos][x_pos] = character
    with open(filename,"w") as file:
        file.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Seriously, though. Check the code, don't just take it. I'm usually pretty good when it comes to python, but file I/O is my weakpoint in every language.

Comment: I did, The idea is right, but I fixed the code up a bit. I get what you were trying to do

Comment: Would you mind editing my answer to include your edits?

Answer (score 0):

The first, your code will have an infinite loop:

`while True:` Do you have any check variable?

The second, I don't think this one can work for you: `f.writeline[0]=+1`

I'm not sure that my recommend code can help you fix your issue, but if it doesn't match your idea, please comment it.

```py
check = True
# file = '1)5'
add_val = 5
while check:
    open('file', 'w').write(add_val + ",")
    add_val += 1
    if add_val > 20: # condition to break the while loop
        check = False
f = open('file','r').read()
print (f)
```

Comment: Okay, I left out one thing. I am hoping to replace a specific character within my file (Otherwise, thanks a lot. People aren't usually this patient when it comes to helping). Fore example:

File contents:John is six

If I wanted to replace the "J" in "John", what would I do? And how would I do it within a loop statement if the variable changed? (I do believe that Jakob made a good piece of code, so let me get back to you on that)